# problem with polar coordinates in plots

Tags: plotting

when I set plot range on 300, polar coordinates as is shown in figure 1 is completely covered but figure range is so far away from outer degree circle and When I set plot range on 200, polar coordinate is not shown in plot clearly,I am thankful if you guide me to fix it

```
Q = PolarPlot[
      {(100*Cos[t]*Cos[t])/(1.5*(1-0.49)^(1/2)), 
       (100*Sin[t]*Sin[t])/(1.5*(2-0.49)*(1 - 0.49)^(3/2))}, 
      {t, 0, 2*Pi},
      PolarAxes -> True,
      PlotRange -> 300,
      PolarGridLines -> {Automatic, None},
      PolarTicks -> {"Degrees", Automatic}
    ]
```

[image: plot with PlotRange set to 300]

[image: plot with PlotRange set to 200]

Comment: Along with `PlotRange -> 200`, use the option `PlotRangePadding -> 25`

Comment: More hacky solution, draw an invisible circle with `PolarPlot[170, {\[Theta], 0, 2 Pi}, 
 PlotStyle -> {Directive[Opacity[0]]}]` and then combine that with `Show` with your `polarplot`.

Comment: @Max1, thank you bro.

Comment: @Bob Hanlon, thanks a lot

Answer (score 3):

In addition to setting a `PlotRangePadding` as Bob Hanlon suggested in comments, you may also want to play with `PolarAxesOrigin` to fine-tune the appearance of the plot:

```
PolarPlot[
  {(100*Cos[t]*Cos[t])/(1.5*(1 - 0.49)^(1/2)), 
   (100*Sin[t]*Sin[t])/(1.5*(2 - 0.49)*(1 - 0.49)^(3/2))},
  {t, 0, 2*Pi},
  PolarAxes -> True,

  (*----------*)
  PolarAxesOrigin -> {Pi/4, 150},
  PlotRange -> 130, PlotRangePadding -> Scaled[0.15],
  (*----------*)

  PolarGridLines -> {Automatic, None},
  PolarTicks -> {"Degrees", Automatic}
]
```

[image: polar plot with fine tuning of position of axes and range padding]

[`PolarAxesOrigin`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/PolarAxesOrigin.html) allows you to control the angular position of the polar axis as well as the distance from the origin at which the radial axis crosses the angular axis.

Comment: thank you so much, it was very helpful.